# Can't remotely debug on Java 9 Tomcat 9 in docker container

Tags: java, tomcat, docker, remote-debugging, java-9

I have a Docker container based on `opendjdk:8-slim` with installed Tomcat 9 and I am debugging apps deployed there from my IDE (IntelliJ) - the IDE runs on Docker host. I run the Tomcat with the following configuration

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=49520 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=49520 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false \
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.0.75.1 \
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=49540,suspend=n,server=y"
```

Everything works great - I can attach the IDE to the container. Also the following command works (executed from docker host) - it can connect to the process in the container (the port 49540 in the container is mapped to the port 49540 on the host):

```
docker-host$ telnet localhost 49540
```

Now I want to upgrade to Java 9. I changed the base image from `openjdk:8-slim` to `openjdk:9-slim` and I can't connect to the debugger port from the docker host. Also from IDE, I got `SocketTimeoutException: Connection reset`. However, from inside the container I am able to connect to the debugger via `telnet`.

I tried several images of Java 9 from `openjdk` repository and also from other repos, for example `adenix/java`, but unfortunately with the same result.

Comment: Try using `address=0.0.0.0:49540` and see if it helps

Comment: In JDK 9, the JDWP binds to localhost by default, yu may need to specify address=*. More details in the release notes here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-notes-3745703.html#JDK-8041435

Comment: @AlanBateman thanks a lot for the clue! I tried to specify the address - both `*` and the concrete ip address `192.168.16.1`. Now I am getting the following errors during Tomcat startup: `ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Cannot assign requested address
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:730]` I tried to ping the IP address from the container and it was successful.

Comment: "Cannot assign ..." suggests this is not the address when in the docker container. I'm surprised `address=*:49540` doesn't work as that is the equivalent of `address=49540` with JDK 8.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally I found a way how to make it work using information in the comment provided by Alan Bateman.

Instead of setting debug settings in `CATALINA_OPTS` (which worked with JDK 8 without problems), I set `JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=*:4954‌​0,server=y,suspend=n‌​"` and run Tomcat with `catalina.sh jpda run`. The concrete IP address (for instance `address=192.168.16.1:49540`) still doesn't work for me, although the IP address is reachable from within the container.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me on tomcat-9, JDK-11

Comment: The main point is that in Java 8 and older it would listen to all ip addresses when you would specify just a port as `address`, e.g. `address=4954‌​0`.

Starting with Java 9 it will only listen to `127.0.0.1` by default, and you need to explicitly specify that you want to listen to all ip addresses, e.g. `address=*:4954‌​0`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using in my docker-compose.yaml this environment variable to run in the **Java 9** with **Tomcat 9**:

```
...
    environment:
      - "JPDA_ADDRESS=*:8000"
...
```

Before in **Java 8** I was using:

```
...
    environment:
      - "JPDA_ADDRESS=8000"
...
```

Comment: This was also my issue. Now it's working.